# Why my Angular/Rxjs6.5 shareReplay(1) not working?

Tags: angular, typescript, functional-programming, rxjs6, rxjs-observables

I have very simple code in my service class:

```
userContext$ = this.http.post<UserContext>(this.userContextService, {}).pipe(
    shareReplay(1),
    tap((val: UserContext) => (this.userContext = val))
  );
```

This is called twice, first in Header and then in Body:

```
changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class HeaderComponent{

  userContext$ = this.userContextService.userContext$;
```

2nd time:

```
    export class PortfolioComponent {

  userContext$ = this.userContextService.userContext$;
```

But this doesn't seems to work, in my Network Tab I always have 2 calls, even if I do Console.log it's logged twice:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried testing it with a working API? (receiving 200 status code)

Comment: Yup, same result.

Comment: Could you add a picture with the callstack from the debugging view after placing a breakpoint in `Observable`'s callback from `xhr.ts`? (open dev tools  + (CTRL + P) + `xhr.ts`). I'm pretty sure this way we can find out why there are 2 calls. Or even better, see if you can copy it into a gist, as it may be contain a lot of calls. **EDIT**: before anything else, is the service provided at root level?

Comment: @Andrei Before I try the xhr.ts, yeah it’s provided in root, only fishy thing I can think of is that Header is defined in Core module and portfolio is in app module, app module imports core module. service is placed in app module.

Comment: I don’t think this would be a problem as long as the service is provided that way

Comment: @AndreiGătej Yup: @Injectable({
  providedIn: "root",
})
export class UserContextService

Comment: @AndreiGătej Do you mean zone-evergreen.js ? I couldn't find xhr.ts under Source tab in chrome Dev Tools.

Comment: Hmm, it should be shown after pressing CTRL + P and typing in. What about ‘client.ts’?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213546/discussion-between-foo-baar-and-andrei-gtej).

Comment: @AndreiGătej Hi, I posted the issue details below.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was with the instance of my services.

Basically userContext is a singleton class (with a decorator to providedIn: root) and it was called inside PortfolioComponent (PC) directly, somewhow (PC) has it's on service class also which is not scoped globally hence PC had it’s declared as Provider: [PC Service class]. this was forcing cli to create a new instance of userContext every time PC called it.

I solved it by moved the userContext calls in PC service class, like this:

```
 providers: [PortfolioService],
})
export class PortfolioComponent {

  welcomeTitle: string = lables.welcomeTitle;
  active = 1;

  userId$ = this.portfolioService.userId$;
  holdingData$ = this.portfolioService.holdingData$;
  userContext$ = this.portfolioService.userContext$;
  userAnnouncements$ = this.portfolioService.userAnnouncements$;
```

And inside PortfolioService

```
  userContext$ = this.userContextService.userContext$;
  userAnnouncements$ = this.userContextService.userAnnouncements$;

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private userInfoService: UserInfoService,
    private userContextService: UserContextService
  ) {}
```

Thanks to @Andrei Gătej for spending time with me on this.